# Extend arrays of arrays of T where T is Comparable

Tags: swift

I want to create an extension that would extend arrays of arrays of T, where T is Comparable ; a little bit like that:

```
extension Array where Element == Array<T: Comparable> {
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's actually available in Swift 4! You can read about it in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID553)

But here's a snippet (This will compile with the new xcode 9 and above)

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func isTop(_ item: Element) -> Bool {
        guard let topItem = self.last else {
            return false
        }
        return topItem == item
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to extend 2D arrays of equatable elements ! :)